# Supernatural child captured by cultists

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel in the early to mid 2000's though I think it may have been part of a series so details may jump between books with my fuzzy memory.

It's about a young boy, 12-16ish, who has some powers, I believe he can read minds or move objects with his mind. I can't remember the order of details but I think the following events happen:

- He is friends with/runs into a journalist
- He is adopted out into the middle of nowhere by an odd woman (and her son?)
- The woman turns out to be a cultist who needs the boy for a ritual (this boy in particular)
- The ritual takes place at a power facility in the middle of a forest (man made forest, I remember the boy takes note of the trees all in straight lines and gets lost)
- The boy gets chased by dogs (demon dogs?) and runs into the journalist in the middle of a road
- They decide to print the story but are stopped from doing so and are contacted by a professor at a museum (Natural History museum in London?)
- When they go to meet the professor he's been killed and the skeletons start coming to life and start attacking them

I'm hazy on the next detail and it may happen in a future book in the series but I believe the child goes through a door in a church which should lead outside but he ends up in a monastery. Some stuff happens here that I can't remember. He goes back through the door to where he was before and tells the journalist and when they try it again it leads outside like it should.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***The Power of Five: [Raven's Gate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven%27s_Gate)*, by Anthony Horowitz**

Matt, the main character, can move objects with his mind when he smells something burning. His journalist friend is named Richard Cole. He's part of the LEAF program and gets assigned to live with Jayne Deverill. The professor is Sanjay Dravid. The skeletons kill the professor.

Matt meeting Richard, the journalist:

> "Thirsty?" the journalist asked.
>   Matt nodded.
>   The journalist took out a plastic cup and filled it. Matt saw a single bubble of air rise up inside the water. He took the cup. The water was lukewarm.
>   "My name is Richard Cole," the journalist said, sitting down at the table. He produced a notepad and opened it up to a blank page.
>   "I'm Matt," Matthew said.
>   [...]
>   "All right." Matt wasn't sure about this. He had only come to the *Gazette* to ask about Raven's Gate. But there was something about the journalist that seemed trustworthy. He decided to go ahead.
>   And so he told Richard everything that had happened since his arrival in Lesser Malling. He described his first visit to the village and the chemist shop, his meeting with Tom Burgess, the lights and whispering in the forest, his time with Mrs. Deverill, his second meeting with the farmer, and his discovery of the dead body in the bedroom.
>   "...and that's why," he concluded, "I'm trying to find out who or what this Raven's Gate is. It's obviously something important. Tom Burgess died trying to warn me."
>   <sub>*The Gatekeepers/The Power of Five*, book 1: *Raven's Gate*, chapter 9: "Local Affairs"</sub>

Matt is sent to live with an old woman named Jayne Deverill, who is his foster parent for the LEAF project (for juvenile delinquents to rehabilitate):

> Matt looked at the woman who had volunteered to be his foster parent in the LEAF Project. He didn't like what he saw.
>   Jayne Deverill could have stepped out of another century — a time when teachers were allowed to beat children and there were Bible readings before breakfast and tea.
>   <sub>*The Gatekeepers/The Power of Five*, book 1: *Raven's Gate*, chapter 3: "The LEAF Project"</sub>

It's not her son that lives with them, but a farmhand named Noah.

> A man was waiting for them, standing next to an old, beaten-up Land Rover that only seemed to be held together by the mud that covered it. The man was short and very fat, with yellow greasy hair, watery eyes, and a face that seemed to be slowly slipping off his head. He was wearing dirty jeans and a shirt that was too small for him. Matt could see the buttons straining. The man was about forty. He had flabby lips that parted in a wet, unpleasant smile.
>   "Good afternoon, Mrs. Deverill," he said.
>   Mrs. Deverill ignored him. She turned to Matt. "This is Noah," she said.
>   <sub>*The Gatekeepers/The Power of Five*, book 1: *Raven's Gate*, chapter 4: "Lesser Malling"</sub>

Matt is chased by supernatural dogs and is rescued by Richard:

> The flames exploded, leaping almost as high as the power station itself, bright red light flooding the field. At the same time, something black began to take shape within them, molding itself out of the shadows. In seconds the blackness had solidified, and now it leaped — seemingly in slow motion — out of the fire and onto the ground beyond. It was some sort of animal, and moments later a second one appeared, bounding forward to join it. Behind them, the bonfire shrank back to normal size. The wail of the alarm stopped abruptly.
>   They were dogs, but like no dogs Matt had ever seen.
>   [...]
>   For a moment he lay there retching, getting the filthy water out of his system. Then he looked up. And recognized Richard Cole, the journalist from the *Greater Malling Gazette*.
>   "You!" he gasped.
>   "What the...?" Richard was equally surprised.
>   "How..."
>   "What are you doing?"
>   The broken questions hung in the air.
>   Then Matt took control of the situation. "Not now," he said. He was thinking of the dogs. They might have lost the scent when he was in the bog, but they would find it again soon enough.
>   <sub>*The Gatekeepers/The Power of Five*, book 1: *Raven's Gate*, chapter 12: "Out of the Fire"</sub>

The second book, *Evil Star*, indeed involves Matt going through a church and ending up somewhere in Spain.

> Matt hadn't been sure what he would find on the other side of the door. He had been half expecting to step back out into Cannon Street. Instead, he was in a cloister, a covered walkway forming a square around a courtyard with a fountain in the middle.
>   [...]
>   "Let's go out," Richard said. "You need some air."
>   "There is no cloister," Fabian insisted.
>   Angrily, Matt stood up and walked over to the door. "It's through here," he said.
>   He opened the door. And stopped dead.
>   There was no cloister on the other side. There were no flowers, no fountain, no monks. Instead, he found himself looking at an alleyway lined with dustbins and, on the other side, a grimy backyard filled with rubble and broken cement.
>   <sub>*The Gatekeepers/The Power of Five*, book 2: *Evil Star*, chapter 6: "St. Meredith's"</sub>

Comment: Does this series continue with a book where the Nazca lines are actually a celestial lock, only it's calibrated so that there's one star that's not in the right position, so the BBEG uses a satelite to simulate it and release the ancient evil?

Comment: @chif-ii - Yes, that's in *Evil Star*.